# Program Output Issue

Tags: java

I apologize for the lengthy submission but I am having some difficulty with getting this program to work correctly.

There is another Driver program that runs this one and it requires me to print out the name, level, supplies, etc., of a Magician (given certain parameters).

However, when I use the toString() method to print out the String. I continuously get a 
"null" response for my name/level/supplies. My numbers also seem to not update.

Could someone take a look and see what I am doing wrong?

I just can't seem to make the program pick up the Magician parameters.

```
public class Magician
{
    private String name, level, supplies;  
    private int galleons;   
    private double health;

    public Magician(String initialValues)
    {   
        double health = 1000;
        int galleons = 200;
        initialValues = name + "#" + level + "#" + supplies;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name: " + name+
        "Level: " + level +
        "Galleons: " + galleons +
        "Health: " + health +
        "Supplies: " +supplies; 
    }
}
```

This is the beginning of the Driver program that I can not get to print out:

```
public class MagicAndMalice
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Magician harry = new Magician("Harry Potter#apprentice#Owl#Wand");
        System.out.println(harry);  // test toString() method
        System.out.println("------------------------\n\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missunderstanding the value assignment thing in Java. You won't need a separator like `#`, but if you do, you would need to e.g. substr the given String in the constructor.

Here's a short (untested) version, that should clarify what I mean:

```
public class Magician {
    private String name, level, supplies;
    private int galleons;   
    private double health;

    public Magician(String name, String level, String supplies) {
        health = 1000;
        galleons = 200;
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
        this.supplies = supplies;
    }

    // Let's do some Constructor overloading here
    public Magician(String initialValueString) {
        String[] initialValues = initialValueString.split("#");
        this(initialValues[0], initialValues[1], initialValues[2]);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name +
         "Level: " + level +
         "Galleons: " + galleons +
         "Health: " + health +
         "Supplies: " + supplies; 
    }
}


public class MagicAndMalice {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // Method one
        Magician harry = new Magician("Harry Potter", "apprentice", "Wand");
        System.out.println(harry);
        System.out.println("------------------------\n\n");

        // Method two
        Magician ron = new Magician("Ron Weasley#apprentice#Owl");
        System.out.println(ron);
        System.out.println("------------------------\n\n");
     }
}
```

And if you want to have more values than just one in the `supplies` field, have a look at Array or try to split/substr the values with some regular expressions.

Hope that helped to get some clearer about the variable assignment in Java.

Comment: The only problem is that I'm required to use 'initialValues' as a parameter instead of individually splitting them up as you expressed.

Comment: I updated the answer to match that. But be aware: You won't be able to add more than one "supplies" item this way. Perhaps you would need to split the supplies field again with another separator or by using regular expressions in order to enable this feature.

Answer (score 2):

First, you are declaring `health` and `galleons` again. You should not declare them again, just assign the values:

```
health = 1000;
galleons = 200;
```

Also, it seems like you are confused about assignment. If you want to assign some value to `name`, `level` and `supplies`, you have to do:

```
name = ...;
level = ...;
supplies = ...;
```

If `initialValues` will contain a string like `"a#b#c"` and you want to assign each "part" to those variables, you can use `String#split()`:

```
String[] parts = initialValues.split("#");

name = parts[0];
level = parts[1];
supplies = parts[2];
```

**But** I would really recommend you to read a book or follow some tutorials of Java, so you get the basics first.

Comment: Thank you for the input however I'm still confused. I thought the string weren't supposed to be initially assigned values because it is a general Class program that would retrieve the name, level, etc., from the entered parameters in the Driver program.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the code above will be inside the constructor, so you will pass the string in `Magician harry = new Magician("Harry Potter#apprentice#Owl#Wand");`, then the code above will parse that input and assign the corresponding values to the variables `name`, `level` and `supplies`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create object as

```
Magician harry = new Magician("Harry Potter#apprentice#Owl#Wand");
```

only double `health = 1000;` & `int galleons = 200;` get initialled as some value.

When you call `toString()` method then

```
public String toString()
         {
         return "Name: " + name+
         "Level: " + level +
         "Galleons: " + galleons +
         "Health: " + health +
         "Supplies: " +supplies; 
          }
```

the value `null` for some field is returned because it is not initialized at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might make more sense to change your constructor to take separate arguments instead of one string that has to be split up.

```
public Magician(String name, String levels, String supplies, int gallons, double health) {
    this.name = name;
    this.levels = levels;
    ...
}
```

Notice the prefix "this." which prevents name conflicts between the member variables of the class and the parameters passed to the constructor.